「おい、なんでも質問してみせろ」
In the drama 『民王』 泰山 asks his associates to ask him questions in order to prove to them he is the real 泰山:

おい、なんでも質問してみせろ (more context here)

I am fairly familiar with みせる's various usages, but this utterance doesn't seem straightforward to me. "(You should) ask me questions and show"? But shouldn't it be "I am going to let you ask me questions and I will show you (that I am the real 泰山)"? I thought a more intuitive line would be 「みせるから何でも質問しろ！」
Google also confirms my hunch and shows that utterances like 「質問してみせろ」 and 「聞いてみせろ」 are exceedingly rare, with no more than 1-2 hits for either.

Just in case you weren't aware, ～して見せる as a subsidiary verb has special nuances:

10 （補助動詞）動詞の連用形に助詞「て」の付いた形に接続して用いる。
㋐実際にその行為をして、人に示す。「歌って—・せる」「おどけて—・せる」
㋑強い決意を表す。「絶対に勝って—・せる」

For example, 歌ってみせる means singing with the intention of showing it to someone. The nuance is "I'll prove/demonstrate (something) by singing", "I'll show you how I sing", or "Watch me sing".
Regarding なんでも質問してみせろ, this use of みせろ does sound unusual, but it's difficult to make a definitive statement without watching the actual video. The possibilities are:

For some reason, 泰山 is thinking that asking a question to him is challenging or requires determination from the listener. In this case, the nuance would be "Let me see how you (can) ask a question", or maybe even "Ask me anything if you can".
The blog article might simply have a typo, and 泰山 actually said なんでも質問してみろ, not みせろ. Did you watch the actual video?


EDIT: I checked the original video (民王 (2015), Episode 1, 23:40). 泰山 is indeed saying 何でも質問してみせろ, and this does sound odd to me. It definitely should have been 質問してみろ, but this may have been somehow overlooked since the arrogant overtone of みせろ happened to match the speaker's personality.

My apologies for not making my question detailed enough. It wasn't for lack of trying though. I didn't know how else to ask the question I wanted to ask while making sure potential answers knew where I got stuck and how much I knew. 1. Yes I watched the episode and the reason I didn't post a video clip is that I thought 民王 was popular enough that most Japanese people and fluent speakers would have a general idea of its plot (father-son soul exchange). More importantly, although I could record a segment of the drama, upload it, and put a link here there'd be potential copyright issues.


Yes, it is 質問してみせろ in the original drama. Barring posting a recording here I don't know how else I could prove that. My ears are 100% certain they hear みせろ. That's exactly why this utterance confuses me. Your conjecture could work but I find it implausible. In broad strokes the drama tells the story of a father who recently becomes Prime Minister of Japan exchanging souls with his son, a good-for-nothing college student. The part where this line occurs is right after they find out their souls have switched places. To prove he's the real PM 泰山 asks his associates to ask him anything.



What I omitted from my post is pinpointing entry #10 but I thought it would be clear enough with the "subsidiary verbs" tag and a link to the appropriate dictionary entry that I made sure to attach to my question. I thought that tag would tell potential answers that my struggle doesn't reside in differences between the subsidiary usage and other meanings. I understand here it functions as a subsidiary verb and I know てみせる's subsidiary usage fairly well, which is exactly what makes this quote strange sounding to my ear.


@desmo Never mind. I can usually check most recent anime on my video subscription service, but this drama seems too new. If 泰山 definitely said みせろ, then perhaps he is a quite arrogant person? (And I'm sorry I missed the subsidiary-verb tag; very few askers care for tags...)

The original 民王 was aired in 2015 though. The new one that you are referring to might be the sequel that came out recently?

Oh, it's from the 2015 version? Then I can check the video myself. It's in the first chapter?

Thank you so much for taking the time to do that!! I really appreciate it! It's around 23:40 in episode 01.

@desmo Please see my edit. Your concern turned out to be entirely valid, but it seems we can only conclude that this was an odd expression that somehow slipped through.
